# How do I contact the maintainer of an out of date mirror?

Tags: upgrade, updates, mirrors

I have been using ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/distributions/ubuntu/ Mirror for downloading new packages and updates. After Firefox 30 released, I waited for many days for my 14.04 LTS to upgrade from Firefox 29, but didn't get any upgrade.

Later I came to know that Firefox 30 is already there in Ubuntu repos. So, I switched to Main Server and got Firefox 30 and many other updates. What could be reason, why my previous mirror didn't have latest packages? If there's a problem on server side, how can the maintainers of this particular mirror be contacted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most mirror operations are automated, this could be a simple error with that mirror or another problem. Usually if a mirror is out of date for too long it should be removed from the list.

Launchpad has a list of Ubuntu mirrors:

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Here is the entry for the mirror you are using:

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ftp.iitb.ac.in-archive

Click on the owner link to get the contact information for that particular mirror, they may or may not even know their is a problem with their mirror. See also:

- https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-mirrors
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors